# SSRS Reports - Default Select All for key with Duplicates

Tags: reporting-services, default

I have a multivalue parameter which allows the user to select which postcode(s) they wish to report on. A postcode can cross multiple suburbs e.g
3194 Mordialloc
3194 Mentone
3194 Parkdale
When it defaults SELECT ALL, only 1 row per postcode is selected but if you manually click select ALL it selects every row.Is there anyway I can get the default to select ALL (and not select a distinct subset)

This is the dataset that is used to default/populate the postcode parameter

```
select PCode,  pcode + ' ' + Locality as Location, Locality
from postcodes
order by Locality, pcode
The primary key field is PostcodeId.
```

[This is how the parameter displays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tj3wi.png)

[image]

[Postcode Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcEqr.png)

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and post the code you've got so far. That's the only way you can expect any answers. Oh, and welcome to SO! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your parameter dataset query probably needs to use the postcodeID as that's a unique key. You may also have to update subsequent querys as your postcode parameter's value will now be the postcodeID and not the postcode.

so..

```
SELECT PostcodeId,  pcode + ' ' + Locality as Location, Locality
    FROM Postcodes
    ORDER BY Locality, pcode
```

If this is a problem (for some reason not clear in your question) then make sure you use the 'Location' column from the dataset results as the parameter Value and Label.

Basically the problem stems from the fact that your parameter values list id not unique.

Comment: Thanks. It's going to mean quite a lot of changes as everything hinges around the postcode being in the parameter field.

Comment: Actually it was an easy change just added in the unique field to the list returned from the dataset. THANK YOU